# How to access the HTTP request body using RestSharp?

Tags: c#, rest, .net-3.5, client, restsharp

I'm building a RESTful API client using C# .NET 3.5.

I first started building it with the good old `HttpWebClient` (and `HttpWebResponse`), I could do whatever I wanted with. I were happy. The only thing I stumbled upon was the automatic deserialization from JSON response.

So, I've heard about a wonderful library called RestSharp (104.1) which eases the development of RESTful API clients, and automatically deserialize JSON and XML responses. I switched all my code on it, but now I realize I can't do things I could do with `HttpWebClient` and `HttpWebResponse`, like access and edit the raw request body.

Anyone has a solution?

**Edit: I know how to set the request body (with `request.AddBody()`), my problem is that I want to get this request body string, edit it, and re-set it in the request (in other words: updating the request body on the fly)**

Answer (score 62, accepted):

The request body is a type of parameter. To add one, you can do one of these...

```cs
req.AddBody(body);
req.AddBody(body, xmlNamespace);
req.AddParameter("text/xml", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
req.AddParameter("application/json", body, ParameterType.RequestBody);
```

To retrieve the body parameter you can look for items in the `req.Parameters` collection where the `Type` is equal to `ParameterType.RequestBody`.

See code for the `RestRequest` class [here](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/blob/master/src/RestSharp/RestRequest.cs).

Here is what the [RestSharp docs on `ParameterType.RequestBody`](https://github.com/restsharp/RestSharp/wiki/ParameterTypes-for-RestRequest) has to say:

> If this parameter is set, it’s value will be sent as the body of the
>   request. The name of the Parameter is ignored, and so are additional
>   RequestBody Parameters – only 1 is accepted.
>
> RequestBody only works on POST or PUT Requests, as only they actually
>   send a body.
>
> If you have GetOrPost parameters as well, they will overwrite the
>   RequestBody – RestSharp will not combine them but it will instead
>   throw the RequestBody parameter away.

For reading/updating the body parameter on-the-fly, you can try:

```
var body = req.Parameters.FirstOrDefault(p => p.Type == ParameterType.RequestBody);
if (body != null)
{
    Console.WriteLine("CurrentBody={0}", body.Value);
    body.Value = "NewBodyValue";
}
```

Or failing that, create a new copy of the `RestRequest` object with a different body.

Comment: Excellent, thanks ! There is the full working code : http://pastebin.com/0c4bqPNW

Comment: Here instead of `.Where([lambda]).FirstOrDefault()` you can simply do `.FirstOrDefault([lambda])`

Comment: If you want the JSON:`req.JsonSerializer.Serialize(request.Parameters[1])`