# RestSharp get serialized output

Tags: c#, restsharp

I am looking for a way to access the serialized result of the AddBody call.

I am using the built in RestSharp Serializer.
Example:

```
class Foo
{
    public string FooField;
}       

void SendRecord() 
{

    var f = new Foo();
    f.FooField = "My Value";

    request.AddBody(f);

    // How do I get the serialized json result of the add body call without 
    // data? I would like to log the serialized output of the add body call to
    // the database. 
    //Expected {"FooField":"My Value"}

    var response = client.Execute(request);
}
```

Comment: Please provide more detail and code examples.

Answer (score 4):

I also struggled with this (using v107 preview) and couldn't find any examples of logging the actual string sent to the server. The issue I was trying to debug was getting the right serialisation settings so the object was no use to me.

The only way I could find to get the serialized body as a string was to hook into the OnBeforeRequest event on the RestRequest:

```
var request = new RestRequest("/", Method.Post)
    .AddHeader(KnownHeaders.ContentType, "application/json", false)
    .AddJsonBody(myObj);

request.OnBeforeRequest = async (httpRequest) =>
{
    var requestBodyStr = await httpRequest.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
    Trace.WriteLine($"Request body: {requestBodyStr}");
};
```

Comment: Does the method I used no longer work in 107? request.Parameters.Where(p => p.Type == ParameterType.RequestBody).FirstOrDefault();

Comment: @Nikoli - yes it still works and thanks this is still a great way to get the request body as an object. But that can hide some types of issues - I was looking to see what the string value that gets sent over http looked like once serialised (using json.net etc) - so in my case I wanted to check that pascal case was being used and date formats when converting my object to json.

Comment: Cannot resolve symbol 'OnBeforeRequest'

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out by finding [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16768314/how-to-access-the-http-request-body-using-restsharp).

```
request.Parameters.Where(p => p.Type == ParameterType.RequestBody).FirstOrDefault();
```

Comment: This only gets you the object, not the serialized string, at least as of version `106.11.7`.

Answer (score 0):

RestSharp itself doesn't expose the serialized request body when you pass an object to it.

There is a way to get at it though, I just posted over here:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/75537611/2509281

Answer (score -1):

Right off the RestSharp homepage (http://restsharp.org/):

```
// execute the request
RestResponse response = client.Execute(request);
var content = response.Content; // raw content as string <~~~~~~~~~~
```

Comment: That is the response from the server. Not what is being sent by the client

Comment: I figured it out. 
request.Parameters.Where(p => p.Type == ParameterType.RequestBody).FirstOrDefault();