# Log Request/Response in Web Request (FTP) or SFTP calls .Net Core

Tags: c#, ftp, asp.net-core, sftp

Is there a way to override web Request or any other thing to log request/response for every web request(FTP or SFTP) we make.

I want to log it in DB thats why I want to override somehow.

Please note: I am asking solution for asp.net Core only.

Comment: How do you host your asp.net Core application? IIS? Azure? Kestrel?

Comment: IIS, But I want to log request my application make.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Output log using FtpWebRequest](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9664650/output-log-using-ftpwebrequest) - That's for FTP - There's no SFTP in .NET.

Comment: I am using Tamir.SharpSsh.dll for SFTP and its not a duplicate since i need to log in DB.

Comment: who is that pro Coder who wants to close it without answering :(

Comment: And do we know that you use Tamir library? + Tracing can be redirected to DB. + Logging of FTP and Tamir are two unrelated questions  anyway.

Comment: I am sorry, what are you asking?

Comment: I don't know about that may be that's why I have asked a question. If i knew that much, then would I need help? sad critics everywhere man.

Answer (score 0):

Consider using [RestSharp for .net core](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp.NetCore/) and log the `response.Content` which contains the raw response received on the wire, and then you could do like suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24190920/1662254) to get the request body before sending it:

```
request.Parameters.Where(p => p.Type == ParameterType.RequestBody).FirstOrDefault();
```